# Loosing Panel Generated from code behind on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, viewstate, page-lifecycle

I am trying to make a dynamic jquery Tab UI interface that will grow based on my Database values.  When I fire a postback  I loose my Panel containers and it breaks my jquery.  I add the controls on `Page.Init`  Below is the code.  Is there anyway i can A. Move the controls back into the panel? B. Stop my panel from disappearing. I still have all of my GUTS if i only had the container i would be so happy.

```
protected void BindTypes()
{
    string getTypes = String.Format("sp_GetVolumeTypes {0}", _siteID);
    DataTable types = SiteFunctions.dt(getTypes);

    for (int i = 0; i < types.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        li.ID = "title-" + i;
        TabTitle.Controls.AddAt(0, li);


        HtmlGenericControl anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
        anchor.Attributes.Add("href", "#MainContent_" + types.Rows[i][0].ToString());
        anchor.ID = "titleLink-" + i;
        anchor.InnerText = types.Rows[i][0].ToString();


        li.Controls.Add(anchor);

        Panel Place = (Panel)tabs.FindControl(types.Rows[i][0].ToString());

        if (Place == null)
        {
            Place = new Panel();

            Place.ID = types.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            Place.CssClass = "tabs-" + i.ToString();
            tabs.Controls.Add(Place);
            ucViewStateManager.AddControl(Place);
        }
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            //Hidden Type
            HiddenField hdnType = new HiddenField();
            Place.Controls.Add(hdnType);
            hdnType.ID = "hdn" + types.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            hdnType.Value = types.Rows[i][0].ToString();

            ucViewStateManager.AddControl(hdnType);

            LoadFixRates(types.Rows[i][0].ToString(), Place);
            AddEmptyFixRateBox(types.Rows[i][0].ToString(), Place);
            AddEmptyFixRateBox(types.Rows[i][0].ToString(), Place);
            AddEmptyFixRateBox(types.Rows[i][0].ToString(), Place);

        }

    }
    BindRackPrice();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you need to re-create and add dynamic controls to page on every postback. A suitable place for this would be `Page_Load` event handler. It is possible to add controls later, but then dynamic control events will not be fired.